# Optimization problem: smallest euclidean distance with positive entries constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose there is the simple function:

\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)  &= (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 + (x+y-S-z - d)^2
\end{align}

where $a,b,c,d$ are nonnegative constants, and $S$ is an integer. I want to find $x^*=(x,y,z, x+y-S-z))$ with the smallest distance from $(a,b,c,d)$, such that the entries in $x^*$ are greater or equal to zero. This motivates the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\min & \qquad f(x,y,z) \\
\text{subject to}  & \qquad -x \leq 0 \\
& \qquad -y \leq0 \\
& \qquad -z \leq0 \\
& \qquad -(x+y-S-z) \leq 0 
\end{align}
Now, I want to rewrite the problem in an equivalent form where I can eliminate the inequality constraints. First attempt, Try computing the lagrangian we get:
\begin{align}
L(x,y,z\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4) = f(x,y,z) - \lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 y - \lambda_3 z - \lambda_4(x+y-S-z)
\end{align}
I cannot see another formulation of this where I can rewrite this optimization problem in an equivalent form where I can get rid of the Lagrange multipliers? Is this possible?

Comment: if there are equality constrains you work with lagrangian, but for inequalities you need to use karush khun tucker's theorem (its lagrangian plus more conditions ),

Comment: I'm curious why you are insistent on eliminating the inequality constraints. What's wrong with a numerical solution?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not possible getting rid of the inequalities, or the Lagrange multipliers. 
In other words, there isn't a system of equations you can solve.

If you wanna do this so badly, you can always compute a zero of the gradient, and if it doesn't satisfy the inequalities, try to find the minimum in your boundary.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I would suggest you should not insist on finding a closed-form solution to problems like this. There is nothing wrong with the notion that a model is only solvable numerically. Indeed, few actually *interesting* models are!

It looks to me like you've already tried to simplify this, again unnecessarily, before you even posted about it. This seems like the intended model:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2+(w-d)^2 \\
\text{subject to} & x + y + z + w = S \\
                  & x, y, z, w \geq 0
\end{array}
You gain nothing by expressing your model in a manner that is less clear!

But hey, let's see how far we can go with this. To simplify, I'm going to write it this way:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \tfrac{1}{2} \|x-v\|_2^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} (x-v)^T(x-v)\\
\text{subject to} & \vec{1}^T x = S \\
                  & x \geq 0
\end{array}
where $x$ is now a 4-vector and $v=(a,b,c,d)$. I hope you don't mind the $\tfrac{1}{2}$ in the objective; it doesn't change the optimal $x$, but it does simplify some things. The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,\lambda,z) = \tfrac{1}{2} (x-v)^T(x-v) - \lambda ( \vec{1}^T x - S ) - z^T x$$
where the Lagrange multipliers are a $\lambda$ and a *nonnegative* 4-vector $z$.
This leads to the KKT conditions
$$x=v+\lambda\vec{1}+z\qquad \vec{1}^Tx=S \qquad x,z\geq 0\qquad x_iz_i=0,~i=1,2,3,4$$
Combining the first and third conditions leads to these assertions about $x$:
$$x_i \geq 0, ~ x_i \geq v_i+\lambda \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x_i \geq \max\{v_i+\lambda,0\}, \quad i=1,2,\dots, 4.$$ 
But the complementarity conditions tell us that we cannot have *both* $x_i>0$ and $z_i>0$, which means that if $v_i+\lambda>0$, it *must* be the case that $z_i=0$ and $x_i=v_i+\lambda$. So combining the first, third, and fourth conditions leads us to this:
$$
\begin{gathered}
x_i = \max\{v_i+\lambda,0\}  \quad \\
z_i = x_i - v_i - \lambda = \max\{-v_i-\lambda,0\} \qquad (*)
\end{gathered}
$$
Now we're getting somewhere! Here's how we can solve this. First, knock out the easy cases:

1. Compute $s \triangleq \vec{1}^T v = a+b+c+d$.
2. If $s=0$, STOP; $(x,\lambda,v)=(v,0,0)$ is the trivial KKT solution.
3. Otherwise, let $\lambda_0 = \tfrac{1}{4}(S-q)$.
4. If $v+\lambda_0\vec{1}>0$, then STOP; $(x,\lambda,z)=(v+\lambda_0 \vec{1},\lambda_0,z)$ is a KKT solution.

If we're still going, that means that at least one of the inequality constraints $x_i\geq 0$ is active, and $\lambda$ must lie in the interval $(\lambda_0,0)$. We need to find it! Without loss of generality, assume that $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$; i.e., $v_1\leq v_2\leq v_3\leq v_4$. Then we do this:

5. Let k = 1.
6. Let $\lambda_k = \tfrac{1}{4-k} (S- \sum_{i=k+1}^4 v_i)$.
7. If $\lambda_k\in(\lambda_0,0)$ and $v-\lambda_k\vec{1}>0$, STOP.
   $(x,\lambda)=(v+\lambda_k\vec{1},\lambda_k)$, and $z$ calculated
   according to the formula $(*)$ above, is the KKT solution.
8. Set $k\rightarrow k+1$ and repeat steps 6-8.

I know I haven't proven this rigorously, but it fits my intuition and experience. $\lambda$ is controlling how far $x$ deviates from its ideal value, $(a,b,c,d)$. We want $\lambda$ to be as *close as possible* to $\lambda_0$, which is the value required by the equality constraints alone. By setting values of $x_i$ to zero from smallest to largest, we ensure that we're "moving" $\lambda$ by the smallest amount.

It's not a closed form solution, but at $O(n)$ it's hard to beat.